A "simple" proof of the Hahn-Banach spaces for continuous linear maps on a closed subspace of a Hilbert space
I've tried to solve the following problem, but I'm not sure whether I've made some wrong assumptions along the line, so I'd appreciate it if someone could check my solution.
The exercise is:
Give a simple proof of the Hahn-Banach theorem for
a continuous linear form on a closed subspace of
a Hilbert space.

Here is my attempt:
Let $V$ be a Hilbert space and let
$U \subset V$ be a closed subspace. Then
$V = U \oplus U^{\perp}$. Let
$\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for
$U$ and extend it to a basis
$\mathcal{A}$ for $V$. Take the duals
$\mathcal{B}^{'}$ and $\mathcal{A}^{'}$.
For $z \in U^{*}$ we can write
$z = \sum_{y_i' \in \mathcal{B}'}
    a_i y_i$. Then $z$ can also be considered a linear
form on $V$ by letting the coefficient for
$y_i \in \mathcal{A}'$ be $0$ if
$y_i \not\in \mathcal{B}'$ and
$a_i$ otherwise. The restrictions are clearly
the same.
By the Riesz-Fréchet representation theorem,
since $U$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space, it
is also a Hilbert space, so by continuity of $z$, there
exists $u \in U$ such that
$z(x) = \left< x,u \right>$ for all $x \in U$ and
such that $\|z\| = \|u\|$.
But since  $z|_{U^{\perp}} = 0$, we also
have $z(x) = \left< x,u \right>$ for all $x \in V$, so
by the Riesz-Fréchet theorem, $\|z\| = \|u\|$ over $V$ as well.
